# How do i start a sound file without displaying the window of the player ?

Tags: command-line, audio

Whenever I type xdg-open filename or vlc filename, a window opens and start playing the filename. How can I achieve to play the sound file without displaying a corresponding window in the command line ?

Comment: What do you mean by "without displaying a corresponding window in the command line"? Did you mean without a GUI window? If so, you can probably use `aplay` instead.

Comment: `cvlc` is a curses frontend for `vlc`, but if you want a great CLI player, give a look to `mpv`—it's soundly the best.

Answer (score 1):

I've used mocp (MOC). With it you can even add a play list.